# ruby writing content of attachment to file gives me additional new line chracters

Tags: ruby, io

I'm trying to save attachment from gmail to local disk. I'm using gmail gem and following the instructions:

```
gmail.mailbox("Faxes").emails.each do |email|
  email.message.attachments.each do |f|
    File.write(File.join(folder, f.filename), f.body.decoded)
  end
end
```

Issue is when I open file in notepad++ I see after each line new line character added. If I try to add

```
puts f.body.decoded
```

before saving the file, output looks ok (no additional new lines characters).

I have tried different methods how to save content to file but always with same result.
I have ruby 1.9.3 on Win7 installed.
not sure if this is related to ruby, gmail gem or Win7 regional settings. Pls help.

Comment: You should look in the gem's docs regarding ENCONDING. You can check your system enconding in irb: `<?> __ENCODING__`.

Comment: I have tried to change encoding in the beginning of the script and also while saving the content of the file but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 'puts' adds a newline char. If you can use 'print' instead there won't be a new line.  See [puts vs print](http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/ruby/puts-vs-print) for details.

Comment: yes I know that issue is that I have text:
     `Line1
     Line2`
but after saving the file I have:
     `Line1
     <CR>
     Line2`